# Will a toilet flange bolt cause a problem if dropped into the drain pipe?

Tags: toilet, drain-waste-vent

I dropped one of the toilet bolts in the drain hole. It's in the basement and set in concrete. I tried to vacuum it out but couldn't.

How serious is this, will it get flushed down or do I need to trace it it a snake camera and pull it out somehow? The pipe turns horizontal right after the elbow in the ground and it's a 4" pipe.

Or can I just leave it?

Comment: you mentioned the size of the pipe, but you said nothing about the length of the bolt .... that is kind of important

Comment: I think it's 2-3"

Comment: I thought toilet bolts are pretty standard

Comment: Is it a metal that a magnet would attract?

Comment: No, it's brass I believe

Comment: `I thought toilet bolts are pretty standard`  ... how are we supposed to know that kind of a bolt you used?   ..... anyway, a 3" bolt should be too short to wedge inside a 4" pipe,  so i would not worry about it ..... solid waste should push it into the main sewer line fairly quickly

Comment: "how are we supposed to know that kind of a bolt you used?"... he said it in the original question. I do agree though, @jsotola you should make your comment into an answer, without the snarky remark.

Comment: Apparently we're talking about a flange bolt. Could've also been a tank bolt, seat bolt, etc.

Comment: you can flush a lot of ice down the toilet to accomplish 2 things: 1. it could push out a minor obstruction. 2. it can back up and tell you there's a bigger problem (ala needs an auger), while eventually clearing itself out, which is a nicer way to discover the problem than having it backup with other material...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably not an issue. There's a very small chance that it will get caught on a fitting and cause a clog, but more likely it'll either settle somewhere forever or make its way to the septic or municipal sewer. If it does clog a simple auger job should clear it.

Years ago I had my drain augered and the guy dropped a full size Vice-Grip down my aging 3" cast-iron pipe system. He tried for half an hour to retrieve it (magnets not being an option) but was unable. I figured it would come back to haunt me for sure, but it never did.

Comment: Wow a vice grip, I would have expected a problem with that also but not a bolt I haven't seen a vice grip but found quite a few kids toys in tanks over the years.+

Answer (score 0):

Try a magnet!  Go to the hardware store and describe your problem, they should have a ready-made tool with a telescoping wand for reaching and picking up small bolts and other metal.  If you need to reach around a bend in the pipe, you might need to get a strong magnet yourself and put it onto the end of a flexible piece of wire to fish it out.
Good luck!

Comment: Good plan, *if* we're dealing with plastic pipe and a ferrous bolt. We're not, as we've learned in the comments. :)

Comment: Flange bolts are usually brass and a magnet won’t grab them